# C++ errors with typedefs in a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, typedef

I'm trying to write a simple templated event dispatcher but I get compiler errors that I don't understand and searching for it resulted in nothing helpful.
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 express.

Here's my code:

```
template<typename T>
class EventDispatcher {
    public:
        typedef void (EventHandler)(T event);

        EventDispatcher() { }
        ~EventDispatcher() { }

        void addListener(const std::string eventName, EventHandler handler) { }
        void fireEvent(T event) {}

    private:
        typedef std::vector<EventHandler> ListenersList;
        typedef std::map<std::string, ListenersList*> ListenersMap;

        ListenersMap listeners;
        boost::mutex mutex;
};
```

My actual class is a bit more complicated, I simplified it as much as I could to only have what's needed for the compiler to complain.

The errors that I get when compiling:

```
error C2535: 'void (__cdecl *std::allocator<_Ty>::address(void (__cdecl &)(T)) throw() const)(T)' : member function already defined or declared c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 548 1   TestProject
error C2535: 'void (__cdecl *std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<_Ty>>::address(void (__cdecl &)(T)) const)(T)' : member function already defined or declared   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 795 1   TestProject
```

Any idea what's the problem?
If I comment out this line: `ListenersMap listeners;` the errors go away..
Thanks.

Comment: There is no `EventHandler` type, it is templated by T... Such en error appears only when you instantiate the type.

Comment: Have you included <mutex> ? I am not getting any error to anything else than the last line.

Comment: @RobDel the mutex is irrelevant, I should have removed it from the example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that this:

```
typedef void (EventHandler)(T event);
```

declares `EventHandler` to be a *function* type. Not a pointer to function, an actual function. Then, you're trying to create a vector of functions, which of course fails (with a suitably cryptic error message). Change the typedef into a pointer:

```
typedef void (*EventHandler)(T event);
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fc7a75375d1b6da)

Comment: Oh. right. I wish the error messages could have been more helpful in understanding the real problem.